# Weird Segmentation fault in python

Tags: python, pandas

So, I am not sure what is happening here.. I have two python interpreter (one server and one local)...
I have a tab delimited file and I am trying to read this file using pandas. 
Very simple stuff

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\t')
```

But on one machine it throws a

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\t')
Segmentation fault
```

And on another machine it gives following and terminates

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f96f679711e ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bcb)[0x7f97118a5bcb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76f96)[0x7f97118abf96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777de)[0x7f97118ac7de]
/home/msingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.so(parser_cleanup+0x1a)[0x7f96f678da9a]
/home/msingh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.so(+0x16f61)[0x7f96f672cf61]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x585f)[0x5609dc75c58f]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x5609dc755535]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6968)[0x5609dc75d698]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x5609dc755535]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6968)[0x5609dc75d698]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x5609dc755535]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6968)[0x5609dc75d698]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x255)[0x5609dc755535]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x61e9)[0x5609dc75cf19]
```

What is happening here? how do i fix this?

Comment: the file is probably corrupt beyond repair. Can you reproduce it with a small file that you could post here?

Comment: Is it happening locally or on the server?

Comment: @JonClements on both places.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hmm.. very weird.. let me try to regenerate the file.

Comment: You'd have hoped though that a bad input file would error out and be handled more gracefully than letting it segfault the interpreter... @Fraz have you tried on a mocked up file just to check your installation isn't strange... ?

Comment: @JonClements pandas is designed for speed, it must be cutting corners at some point. So if you're feeding it a zipped xml file it may choke :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah i created a sample from file.. which worked fine.. I also checked the end of file.. which also looked fine.. Probably something weird happened.. generating the file again.. hopefully this file is not corrupt. 
yeah.. very weird that python is throwing these errors rather than exceptions

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre unless Panda is _very_ badly implemented (which I doubt), a corrupted file should at most provoke an exception, not a segfault.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, but it's coded in C. Even with very good coding, buffer overflow is lurking in every corner of C code. I can segfault `sed` with a very long line for instance... Anyway, we don't have any reproducer.

Comment: Psst... for large dataframes, try using Dask.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes I understand that, but even then I barely ever got a segfault with any popular C Python extension so I'm really surprised.  Could it be a problem with the OP's panda install ? (linking against a wrong system lib version or whatever...)